# Angular2 ngModel against ngFor variables

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it not possible (or not yet possible) to use `ngModel` against values from `ngFor`?  Is Angular trying to protect me from bad performance?

Works great: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/n5pjgev6/

```
<input type="text" [(ng-model)]="value">{{value}}
```

Does not work so great: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/n5pjgev6/1

```
<li *ng-for="#name of names">
    <input type="text" [(ng-model)]="name">{{name}}
</li>
```

> EXCEPTION: Cannot reassign a variable binding name

I tried binding to the array as well, which... kind of works, but hijacks focus and also throws an exception: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/n5pjgev6/2/

```
<li *ng-for="#name of names; #i = index">
    <input type="text" [(ng-model)]="names[i]">{{name}}
</li>
```

> EXCEPTION: LifeCycle.tick is called recursively

**Edit:**

I can get around the `LifeCycle.tick` issue using a more direct approach, but the focus is still stolen because `ngFor` redraws things: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/n5pjgev6/3/

```
<li *ng-for="#name of names; #i = index">
    <input type="text" [value]="names[i]" (input)="names[i] = $event.target.value">{{names[i]}}
</li>
```

Comment: http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html Read the paragraphs about Managing Transclusion Scope Lifecycle and Repeated Rendering with Element Transclusion. Might give you a bit of insight

Comment: Since a late beta there is `trackBy` available to make `ngModel` work with `ngFor` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469710/angular-2-ngmodel-bind-in-nested-ngfor

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Pretty messed up you'd mark this as a duplicate for your newer answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think `ngFor` don't like tracking array elements which are primitive values having `ngModel` on them.

If you remove the `ngModel` inside the loop, it works.

It works too when I [update jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5pjgev6/5/) with :

```
this.names = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Joe'}, {name: 'Jeff'}, {name: 'Jorge'}];
```

and

```
<li *ng-for="#n of names"><input type="text" [(ng-model)]="n.name">{{n.name}}</li>
```

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it by using a wrapper around my value (exactly what you did above). But let me ask: Is this an Angular 2 bug or "feature"? I am not quite sure why this is happening.

Comment: Not a bug at all. Strings are primitives so there is no reference address and ng2 takes its value instead to identify it inside the loop (ngFor). Then ngModel wants to modify this value -> Exception

Comment: Not tried but I think it behaves almost the same with ng1.

Answer (score 7):

A solution is to reference the value inside `ngModel` by its index. Therefore `[(ngModel)]="names[index]"`.

But this is not sufficient because `*ngFor` tracks items by value. As soon as the value is changed the old value cannot be tracked. So we need to change the tracking function to return an index, thus `trackBy: trackByIndex`.

This issue is explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423).

**Solution:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" 
        *ngFor="let name of names; let nameIndex = index; trackBy: trackByIndex"
        [(ngModel)]="names[nameIndex]"/>
      <br/>
      {{ names | json }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  names: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  }

  public trackByIndex(index: number, item) {
    return index;
  }
}
```