# Angular 2 ngModel bind in nested ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm attempting convert an Angular 1 app to Angular 2. Looping through a jagged array of booleans `(boolean[][])`. I'm rendering out `checkboxes` with the following code:

```
<div *ngFor="#cell of CellData; #parentIndex = index">
    <input *ngFor="#col of cell; #childIndex = index" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="CellData[parentIndex][childIndex]" />      
</div>
```

The checkboxes display correctly, however, if I select a checkbox the one to the right of it is also selected.

This logic works fine in the Angular 1 app so I'm not sure if it's a problem with the way I am using ngModel or an issue with Angular 2.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: See this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/BbZxbAS0jNafAfI6slq9?p=preview, @Gunter. Really strange the associated corresponds to the updates but the view is desynchronized...

Comment: Got to it first, I was just about to post a plunker for it ;)

Comment: Thank you @ScottLyons, I was facing the problem of using ngModel inside ngFor, didn't get any way to do it, your question helps me. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**

The official way to use `ngForTrackBy` seems to be

```ts
      <input 
          *ngFor="let col of cell; let childIndex=index; trackBy:customTrackBy" 
          type="checkbox" 
          [(ngModel)]="CellData[parentIndex][childIndex]" />
```

See http://angularjs.blogspot.co.at/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html for more details

note the `:` in `trackBy:customTrackBy`

**original**

You can use `*ngForTrackBy` for this:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let cell of CellData; let parentIndex = index">
      <input 
          *ngFor="let col of cell; let childIndex = index" type="checkbox" 
          *ngForTrackBy="customTrackBy" 
          [(ngModel)]="CellData[parentIndex][childIndex]" />      
    </div>

    Data:<br/><br/>
    {{CellData | json}}
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.CellData = [
      [ true, false, true, false ],
      [ false, true, false, true ]
    ]
  }

  customTrackBy(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
}
```

Angular by default tracks the object identity but different `true`s and `false`s have the same identity. Without `*ngForTrackBy` Angular looses track which `true` or `false` is at which position. With `*ngForTrackBy="customTrackBy"` we make `*ngFor` use the index instead of object identity.

**[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0bRh5FmmaxJOYS5HbFlj?p=preview)**

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4402