# Filling an array of objects using *ngFor and ngModel

Tags: angular

I created the following form in order to add items to an array of ingredients.
When the user clicks " Add a new Ingredient ", an empty ingredient is added to the list.

HTML:

```
<button md-button
              (click)="addIngredient()">
        <md-icon>add</md-icon> ADD
      </button>

    <div *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
        <md-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
          <input mdInput placeholder="NAME"
                 [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name" name="name">
        </md-form-field>
        <md-form-field floatPlaceholder="never" style="width: 80px">
          <input mdInput placeholder="QUANTITY" type="number"
                 [(ngModel)]="ingredient.quantity" name="quantity">
        </md-form-field>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
addIngredient() {
// outputs real list
console.log(this.ingredients);
this.ingredients.push({
      name: 'tt',
      quantity: '12'
    });
}
```

The app starts, and I click "Add" to add a new empty ingredient to the list.
I updated the ingredient name and quantity, and then click "ADD" again to add another ingredient.

when I click the "ADD" button to add another ingredient, the form inputs of all the previous ingredients I added are set to the values I declared in the `addIngredient()` method (all names are showing as 'tt' and quantity is '12') although console log shows the real list.

Any idea what causes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use *input/ngModel* inside ngFor, you have to give unique value for attribute *name* of each input, so you have to generate unique id for each ingredient (I provided an exemple function that generate unique id):

```
<button md-button (click)="addIngredient()">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon> ADD
</button>

<div *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
    <md-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
      <input mdInput placeholder="NAME"
             [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name" name="name-{{ingredient.id}}">
    </md-form-field>
    <md-form-field floatPlaceholder="never" style="width: 80px">
      <input mdInput placeholder="QUANTITY" type="number"
             [(ngModel)]="ingredient.quantity" name="quantity-{{ingredient.id}}">
    </md-form-field>
</div>

addIngredient() {
    this.ingredients.push({
        id: this.guid(),
        name: 'tt',
        quantity: '12'
    });
}

private guid() {
    let uniqueId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2) 
       + (new Date()).getTime().toString(36);
    return uniqueId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add an index in your ngFor, I dont really know how to explain the behavior of ngFor with indexation, but keeping an eye on which item of the array you are may work :

```
<button md-button
          (click)="addIngredient()">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon> ADD
  </button>

<div *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients; let i = index">
    <md-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
      <input mdInput placeholder="NAME"
             [(ngModel)]="ingredients[i].name" name="name">
    </md-form-field>
    <md-form-field floatPlaceholder="never" style="width: 80px">
      <input mdInput placeholder="QUANTITY" type="number"
             [(ngModel)]="ingredients[i].quantity" name="quantity">
    </md-form-field>
</div>
```

EDIT : I based my answer on this post ([Angular2 ngModel against ngFor variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346677/angular2-ngmodel-against-ngfor-variables))